# Git: preserve branch topology on a merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge

I would like to ask about Git merging in the following scenario:

```
branchA  -*-*-*-*-*
                   \
            branchB *-*-*-*
```

It is possible to do a git merge in this case an obtain the following result?

```
branchA  -*-*-*-*-*---------*
                   \       /
            branchB *-*-*-*
```

What I would like to obtain is to have a single merge commit on branchA, that incorporates all changes from branchB.
I know that there is --squash option in git merge command, however I wasn't sure whether that would be 100% equivalent to standard merge.

Thus allow me to prevent my branch topology and *not* have just a fast forward.

Thank you very much in advance for help!

Comment: Why you would want to have that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My motivation is the following: let's assume that branchA is a kind of mainline branch and branchB is a development branch. Some commits on branchB might not be compiling/passing test suite, but in the end branchB is ready to go to mainline. I would like to have one commit on the mainline because it represents finished work and at the same time I can see the history on branchB (in case it is needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `git merge branchb --no-ff` (from `brancha`). From [git-merge(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

> --no-ff
>
> Create a merge commit even when the merge resolves as a fast-forward.

It prevents a fast-forward even when git realizes that the current HEAD (branch A, since this is where you will be merging form) is nothing but an ancestor of commit on branch B, without any changes that took place in parallel on branch A.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot generate a real merge commit which incorporates all of the changes from a branch. `git merge --squash` would generate a single commit with the changes, but it would not be a merge commit.

Git commits record a complete state of the repository at a given time, not the changes from the previous commit(s). So the differences are generated when you later examine the history not when a commit is created.

However, if you use `git commit --no-ff branchB` to create the merge that will ensure that a commit is created even if it would be possible to do a fast-forward merge without creating a new commit. Then if you use `git log -m --first-parent` it would ignore the commits that were made on branchB making it appear that all of those changes were introduced by that merge commit, and the `-m` option would cause the full diff to be displayed for the merge commit (if diffs are otherwise being displayed).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried the git merge branchB --no-ff and that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.